# Firefox: find and select element

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

In Firefox, is it possible to find a button on a page based on text, then select/click that element e.g., CTRL+F, "Post", Post button is select now click another hot key to click the Post Button.

Answer (score 1):

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-contents-current-page-text-or-links?redirectslug=Searching+within+a+page&redirectlocale=en-US#w_quick-find

> If you want to find only phrases that occur in links on the page you're viewing:
>
> 1. Type ' (single quote character) while not into a text field to bring up the Quick Find (links only) bar.
> 2. Type a search phrase into the Quick Find (links only) field. The first link that contains the phrase you've typed will be selected.

Doesn't work on all buttons unfortunately, only those that contain links.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. Firefox's only keyboard shortcuts for the developer tools apply when there is no element selected. See the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector